# A system like trigger to update user statistics

Tags: php, triggers, phpmyadmin, mysql

I want to update user statistics when the insert or delete processed.

I have a table names as userstat and this table contains informations like user_id,playcount,addedgame etc.

When the user play a game on site,I sent a post request to updateuserstat function and function calculate new count of game plays and update on userstats.

But,I think this system is not completely perfect because I see wrong informations on userstats.More or less count from original datas.

Is there any way to be sync gameplay function and updateuserstat function with strong engagement?

Like trigger or something like that.

Comment: What did you try? Could you paste your code in?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has triggers which can be defined on a table to execute on insert/update/delete:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html